# Why we should use ToString method with StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, string, tostring, stringbuilder

MSDN says we need to convert `StringBuilder` object to `string`, but `StringBuilder` works fine?
Why should we convert?

```
string[] spellings = { "hi", "hiii", "hiae" };

StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();

int counter = 1;

foreach (string value in spellings)
{
    Builder.AppendFormat("({0}) Which is Right spelling? {1}", counter, value);
    Builder.AppendLine();
    counter++;
}

Console.WriteLine(Builder); // Works Perfectly
//Why should i use tostring like below
Console.WriteLine(Builder.ToString());
// Does it make any difference in above two ways.

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There is no override of Console.WriteLine for StringBuilder arg. So it just calls with Object arg and then use .ToString() internally, so they both do the same thing

Comment: You don't need to use `.ToString()` if specifically calling `Console.WriteLine`, but you are going to need it for almost all other things.

Answer (score 10):

These two calls use different `Console.WriteLine` overloads: [`WriteLine(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) and [`WriteLine(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf2k8ftb.aspx).

And the `WriteLine(object)` overload calls "... the ToString method of value is called to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream." ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx))

**Edit**

The only difference here I can see is:

```
StringBuilder sb = null;
Console.WriteLine(sb); // prints terminator
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // throws NullReferenceException
```

Comment: and WriteLine(Object obj) probably calls obj.ToString()

Comment: @x4rf41 `WriteLine(object)` *definitely* calls `ToString`.

Comment: And despite the fact, that these two calls do effectively the same, explicitly calling ToString seems better choice, as it improves code readability.

Comment: +1. I also agree with @BartoszKP, also because not every method has an overload that accepts an `object` besides a `string`. `Console.WriteLine` (and `string.Format`) are probably rare cases that have such overloads. But the general case is: If you need a `string`, then state this explicitly, instead of relying upon a third party to produce it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In that specific example, both work fine, because `Console.WriteLine` will call the `ToString()` for you, on anything you pass it. The following also works:

```
 Console.WriteLine(3); //called with an int;
 Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
 Console.WriteLine(new {}); //called with an object
```

However, since the `StringBuilder` is not a string, (but an object that can make a string for you), you cannot pass it to a method that expects a string, i.e.

```
public void PrintMe(string value)
{
   Console.WriteLine(value);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
PrintMe(sb); // this will not work
```

Comment: +1 for the anonymous empty object... I didn't know you could create it (but in the end, this isn't javascript... It's nearly useless)

Answer (score 0):

Both lines of code to write to the console are doing the same thing in a different way. The second is more obvious though.

`Console.WriteLine(Builder);` uses the overloaded `WriteLine()` method that takes an object. As mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx) the `ToString()` method will be called on the `Builder`:

> 'If value is null, only the line terminator is written. Otherwise, the
>   ToString method of value is called to produce its string
>   representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard
>   output stream.'

In the second line `Console.WriteLine(Builder.ToString());` you are calling the `ToString()` method explicitly. This is preferable because it is immediately apparent to a developer what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

this is from code-behind on a web form. i appended several times to my StringBuilder and accidentally did

```
return "[" + sbFinalContents + "]";
```

and i haven't had any trouble with it. i accidentally left off the ToString() part and i didn't even notice for a few days. any idea why this does not blow up?

[StringBuilder.ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1063zt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (.net 4.) : "You must call the ToString method to convert the StringBuilder object to a String object **before you can pass the string** represented by the StringBuilder object **to a method that has a String parameter or display it in the user interface.**"

technically, i'm not doing either one (i'm just returning a string), but i'm still surprised it hasn't failed.